# How to remove whole node in firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have bellow structure of database

[image]

This command remove my whole db

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
firebaseRef.child(`users/${uid}/todos`).remove().then(() => { console.log('ok') });
```

`console.log(firebaseRef)` shows `U {u: Qg, path: E, m: lf, Nc: false, then: undefined…}`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any error showing in your JavaScript console? What is printed when you add `console.log(uid)` right before this code?

Comment: Did you consider using Admin SDK? It provides better functionality

Comment: `console.log(uid)` - gKzx6l1Zp0QeQhfNBPFqa1mZNaz1
and I do not have any errors in console

Comment: @ Ziya ERKOC , for me it's ok, but I have not seen better functionality, can you give me a link

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
firebaseRef.child(`users/${uid}/todos`).remove().then(() => { console.log('ok') });
```

to

```
firebaseRef.child(`/users/${uid}/todos`).remove().then(() => { console.log('ok') });
```

Comment: If the only change you made is adding the leading `/`, that won't make a difference. Since OP is building the reference from the root, the leading `/` makes no difference.

Comment: I'm sorry. I recall having run into a similar problem when I was starting out with Cloud Functions, and I vaguely remember making the same mistake. But, that was some time back so, perhaps I'm just a bit foggy on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that removing actually works fine, but in case if you remove last element in node, firebase remove the whole node(s) automatically
To prevent it we just need to add some value to node